# Using a volatile function to prevent dead code elimination

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, volatile

I'm trying to benchmark some very simple code but it's being removed by compiler optimizations. I've tried to add a call to a function I've marked as volatile to make the compiler think the value is being used for something but it still removes all the code anyway. Here's the code:

```c
volatile void important_function(int *p){
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int *p = malloc(argc);
    for (int i=0; i < argc; i++){
        p[i] = i;
    }
    important_function(p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I use a volatile function call to prevent the code related to `int *p` being removed by optimisaiton passes? I would like to maintain as much optimisation as possible on the code.

Comment: The compile command would also be helpful. Perhaps turning off optimisation?!

Comment: @EdHeal: "maintain as much optimisation as possible..."

Comment: Better try `volatile int x= important_function(p);` where `important_function` returns an `int`. Alternatively `if (p[5]) free(p);`

Comment: `volatile int x = important_function(p);` does the trick. I wonder why? But anyway, feel free to add this as an answer and I'll mark it as a solution, thanks.

Comment: show full code.

Comment: Just edited it to be a full program, the only difference is the loop is now under a main function though.

Comment: These benchmarks with removed optimizations are quite useless. You should benchmark a fully optimized code.

Comment: I assure you what we're doing makes sense for what we're researching.

Comment: One trick that might (or might not) help is putting the called function (`important_function()`) into a separate source file from the calling function.  That limits the opportunities for the compiler to remove code in each source file.  Link-time optimization (LTO) might still remove code.

Comment: I'm not convinced that applying the `volatile` qualifier to a function's return type means what you seem to be hoping that it means; indeed, I'm not sure it means anything useful at all.  The standard says ([§6.7.3 Type qualifiers ¶9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p9): _If the specification of a function type includes any type qualifiers, the behavior is undefined._

Comment: dont' understand. Why nnot showing the real code of `important_function` ? if some code is removed by optimization, there is usually a good reason for it.

Comment: Also you should qualify the variable inside your function as volatile, not the function itself

Comment: If you mark the function with `__attribute__((used))` it will mark it as used for the compiler

Comment: @Carson: `used` will make sure a definition for it appears in the output, in case it's only called from hand-written asm.  But that doesn't stop the compiler from optimizing away calls to it. For that, you need `__attribute__((noinline,noipa))` in GCC (no Inter-Procedural Analysis).  With just noinline, GCC could see that the function had no side effects and decide not to call it (rather than inlining the body and then optimizing it away).  https://godbolt.org/z/o8G4dzejv

Comment: clang doesn't know `noipa`, but `noinline` isn't sufficient; it does still optimize away the call.  (And also the malloc/free pair.)